# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception;

Tags: java, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

when i ran my spring stream application, i got some error, and i don't know why, is there anybody can help me. This is my yml file main content :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
          consumer:
            concurrency: 4
            resetOffsets: true
            auto:
              offset:
                reset: latest
      kafka:
          binder:
              zk-nodes: localhost:2181
              brokers:  localhost:9092
              autoAddPartitions: true
              resetOffsets: true
              startOffset: latest
      bindings:
         gpsin_channel:
         destination: gpssource
         group: gpssource
         consumer:
            concurrency: 10
```

the java class main content :

```
@EnableBinding(AllStreamChannel.class)
public class CarCanSink {

@Autowired
private TspPlatformClient platformClient;
@StreamListener(AllStreamChannel.GPS_IN_CHANNEL)
public void receiveGps(BossGpsStreamVo gpsStream) {
    String judgeFenceInfo = null;
    String sn = vihicleGPS.getTboxSn();
    try {
       judgeFenceInfo = platformClient.getFenceJudgeInfoBySn(sn);
       if (StringUtils.isBlank(judgeFenceInfo)) {
           logger.info("get fenceinfo from db by sn[{}] is null", sn);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error(String.format("get fenceJudge info from db by %s failed, exp : %s",
               sn, ThrowableUtil.getErrorInfoFromThrowable(e)));
    }
}
}
```

when code running into method `receiveGps` ,and use `platformClient`, sometimes, will get some errors like :

```
[10:09:45:898] [ERROR] - 
com.testdemo.tsp.streamtask.sink.CarCanSink.getFenceInfo(CarCanSink.java:834) - 
get fenceJudge info from db by  J16219SI1080001 failed, exp : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.ribbonPing
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.createContext(NamedContextFactory.java:116)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getContext(NamedContextFactory.java:85)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getContext(SpringClientFactory.java:120)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.named.NamedContextFactory.getInstance(NamedContextFactory.java:121)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getInstance(SpringClientFactory.java:110)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory.getClientConfig(SpringClientFactory.java:67)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.getClientConfig(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:78)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:62)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.getFenceJudgeInfoBySn(Unknown Source)
at com.testdemo.tsp.streamtask.sink.CarCanSink.getFenceInfo(CarCanSink.java:828)
at com.testdemo.tsp.streamtask.sink.CarCanSink.receive(CarCanSink.java:495)
at com.testdemo.tsp.streamtask.sink.CarCanSink$1.run(CarCanSink.java:415)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.get(BeanTypeRegistry.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:185)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:190)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:171)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:139)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't know why, it's like the `@Autowired` for `platformClient` is not worked, but this error is not occured all the time, I already add

`@Service
@FeignClient("tsp-platform-service")`

for  interface TspPlatformClient, and it can work correctly most time, is there anyone got the same troumble like me? and how do you resolve this problem, please tell me the solution to this problme, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd love to help, but this issue is not related to Spring Cloud Stream. Consider raising it with Feign/Netflix forums

Comment: `NullPointerException` from the `ConstructorResolver` during bean instantiation - sounds like you have some versions incompatibility. Would be better to rely on the dependencies provided by the Spring Cloud. I mean don't specify a version for any Spring Framework modules. Otherwise, please, share the simple project to let us to play. But since the error is reported not against your, that can be only a versions mismatch problem.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky ok, i already reset `netflix-feign` label for my question.Thanks

Comment: @ArtemBilan I checkout my pom.xml and there no specify version for spring  framework modules,

Comment: Ok! So, share a simple project to reproduce, please! Not sure that we can help otherwise

Comment: @ArtemBilan  there's some thing i want to tell you, i have never met this error in localhost (that means on my own computer), it just occured on our server, even i can't easily reproduce this problem also, it's so confused